# NullPointerException when using MapActivity with ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, itemizedoverlay, mapactivity

I got a `NullPointerException` while using MapActvity

The exception result is :

```
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getIndexToDraw(ItemizedOverlay.java:211)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.draw(ItemizedOverlay.java:240)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-19 15:34:23.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where the code for the MapActivity is :

```
package pit.opensource.mapapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;

public class M1MapAppActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MyOverlays itemizedoverlay;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    private GeoPoint myLocation;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

        // Configure the Map
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(1); // Zoon 1 is world view



        Criteria c = new Criteria();
        //c.setAccuracy(Criteria)
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

        //myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        //mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

        /*myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myLocation =  myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
            }
        });*/

        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.point);
        itemizedoverlay = new MyOverlays(this, drawable);
        createMarker();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

        //  createMarker();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    private void createMarker() {
        Log.e("Create Marker","-------------");


    //  GeoPoint p = mapView.getMapCenter();
    //  OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p,"Title: Abu Said Resturant","Best Falafel in Gaza :) ");

        Place p1 = new Place();
        p1.point = new GeoPoint(345455545, 454558545);
        p1.Title = "PIT";
        p1.Description = "Open source course";

        mapController.animateTo(p1.point); // mapController.setCenter(point);

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlayItem(p1);

        Log.d("Itemized overlay=========",itemizedoverlay.size()+"");
        if (itemizedoverlay.size() > 0) {
            mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    //  myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    //  myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onResume();
    //  myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    //  myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
    }


}
```

and the following is the code for MyOverlay:

```
package pit.opensource.mapapp;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MyOverlays extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlays= new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context context;

    public MyOverlays(Context context, Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {

        Log.d("*******createItem",overlays.get(i).getTitle());
        return overlays.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        Log.d("Item size ", overlays.size()+"");
        return overlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(Place p) {

        Log.d("Overlay item ------ ",p.Title);
        OverlayItem o = new OverlayItem(p.point, p.Title, p.Description);
        overlays.add(o);

    }

    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem overlayItem = overlays.get(index);
        String title = overlayItem.getTitle();
        Toast.makeText(context, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    };

}
```

Comment: where you are calling populate() method on MyOverlays ?

Comment: see this https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/NooYawkAsync/ maybe helpful